# Armature is moving weird on Unity made in Blender

Tags: animation, rigging, transforms, unity

I'm developing a game making in Unity.

I made a character on Blender include meshes, armature, etc.

I exported each animation separately from my rig to fbx files and I combinate on Unity as setting up Root bone.

When I made my character on Blender, the animation of rigs moves as I expected. But when I Imported on Unity It happens like this.

[image]

On Blender

[image]

On Unity

[image]

As you see, the rotation and position of the mesh that I made are changing weirdly which should not move at all.

When I export animation files, I checked option as [Check only Armature, Apply Transform, FBX Unit Scale, Only Deform Bones, Armature FBXNode Type - Root, NLA Strips]. I tried other options but rather it does not solve my problem and showing up unexpected issues.

Also, I applied Humanoid Rig on Unity.

I guess there is a problem on the origin of my rig when I export to fbx and import to unity but I don't know how to fix this issue.

What other options could I try?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To rule out Unity from the equation there are 2 things to try.
1. try removing the key frame optimisation in the inspector / animation settings.
2. Import your exported FBX back into a new blender scene, do you see the same issue in blander.

If 1 fixes it, it’s the Unity keyframe optimisation settings.

If 2 shows the same issue as you get in Unity then the issue lies in the rig and or blender export.

Answer (score 0):

You should check how many bones are affecting the vertices, unity has a limit of 4 bone influences per vertex. If you have more than 4 Unity might optimize them in a way you would not prefer.